# Simpler way to remove characters from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, arr

i have an array of reviews that i would like to result in a single string, with all characters except `a-z` and `'` removed

EDIT:: i actually wish to have all characters except `a-z` and `'` removed, keeping just one whitespace between words, and lowercasing any capitals

here is my current code, which works,

```js
let words = ["A great product for daily use",
"Great price. Takes about 10days for delivery",
"Excellent value - will buy again",
"Fine, I always use this, was as expected",
"Good value",
"excellent product, good value",
"good",
"does the job!",
"Thank you",
"Great it's that is easy to use",
"I hated it",
"arrived on time, excellent product, thank you",
"quick service great price.",
"good and refreshing",
"My daughter is road testing this, but so far it's refreshing",
"DO NOT BUY THIS PRODUCT",
"Avoid",
"Did not notice any difference",
"Horrible taste",
"Does its job and shows it works"]

joinedwords = words.join(' ')
removeChars = joinedwords.replace(/[^\w]/gi, " ").toLowerCase()
replaceApos = removeChars.replace(/it\ss\s/g, "it's ")
replaceNum  = replaceApos.replace(/[0-9]/g, "")
replaceWhi  = replaceNum.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ")
```

but can anybody suggest a better / more efficient/ simpler way to fix?

can regexp be chained into one if they require different outputs?

thanks

Comment: just  do it in one go `words.join(' ').replace(...).replace(...)...` etc

Comment: Your code seems to do more than what you describe. It also removes repeated spaces and modifies "it s " to "it's ", which seems a quite arbitrary spelling update, as there are hundreds of such improvements you could do in a text... So what is the purpose? Only remove all characters except letters and quotes? Or more?

Comment: two of your regex are replacing to the same thing, you could combine them to one.

Comment: @trincot i did mention i want to remove all characters except a-z and '  as a n apostrophe, and yes, also only want one whitespace between words

Comment: @Nicolas this is what i cant work out, when i try to replace non alphanumerical [^\w], it doesnt remove the numbers

how can i chain a regex to look for    [^\w]   AND   [0-9]   ??

Comment: @TheoWright Number are alphaNUMERICAL characters. You could add number to another capturegroup : `[^\w]*[\d]*`. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/ccLHh0/1).

Comment: i didn't know how to chain within a single regex, i fixed it now with this:     
(/[!,.-]*[0-9]*/g, "")

Comment: `[^'a-zA-Z]` will do what you described but your code seems to want to do more so you should clarify your actual needs instead of relying on people to guess.

Comment: It is really confusing that you post code that does *more* than you describe. Please update your question. And what you write above "I fixed it now with this...": that is not in line with what you asked. It does not remove many other punctuation marks and other symbols.

Comment: fair call, edited as mentioned

Answer (score 2):

```js
let words = ["A great product for daily use",
"Great price. Takes about 10days for delivery",
"Excellent value - will buy again",
"Fine, I always use this, was as expected",
"Good value",
"excellent product, good value",
"good",
"does the job!",
"Thank you",
"Great it's that is easy to use",
"I hated it",
"arrived on time, excellent product, thank you",
"quick service great price.",
"good and refreshing",
"My daughter is road testing this, but so far it's refreshing",
"DO NOT BUY THIS PRODUCT",
"Avoid",
"Did not notice any difference",
"Horrible taste",
"Does its job and shows it works"];

joinedwords = words.join(' ');
removeChars = joinedwords.replace(/[^A-Za-z' ]/g, "").toLowerCase();

//Prints result
document.write(removeChars);
```

Tadaa. I ran your code, the ran mine, and they seem to share both the same results so I'm guessing this is what you wanted? Here's how the regex works BTW, it matches any character which is not an alphabet, space nor an apostrophe.

```
joinedwords = words.join(' ')
removeChars = joinedwords.replace(/[^A-Za-z' ]/g, "").toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Could also just do lower casing first for a simpler regex, ``joinedwords.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z' ]/g, "")``

Answer (score 1):

One possible way if you wished to do it without a regex would be to use array filtering like this:

```js
const allowedChars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\''.split('');
let arr = words.join(' ').toLowerCase().split('');
let finalStr = arr.filter(letter => allowedChars.includes(letter)).join('');
```

This allows a super readable way of configuring what letters are allowed